# Eigenvalue problem and finding natural frequencies

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a eigenvalue problem and I have to find the five lowest natural frequencies.

$$\begin{align}\frac{d}{dx}\left[\alpha(x)\frac{dy}{dx}\right]&=\lambda\alpha(x)y \\
\alpha(x)&=1+0.1x\\
y(0)&=0 \\ \frac{dy}{dx}&=0 \end{align}$$

Problem statement says to determine the five lowest natural frequencies by plotting the eigenvalue equation and determining where it crosses the axis. I was told that to sovle this for a bessels function problem to use the transcendental equation for the plot to find the where they cross the axis. I've where I'm stuck is on what exactly to use to plot. The book doesn't show a good job on how exactly to create the plots or what to use to create the equations. If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: On what interval are you working? Where is $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$?

Comment: Sorry about that. I thought for sure I had that added. It's $\frac{dy}{dx}(1)=0$